# Choosing capacitor for RF coupling

Tags: capacitor, rf, coupling, ceramic, vhf

I want to couple 10W at 150MHz, 50 Ohms (before and after an RF switch). The PA is a [RA08H1317M](http://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/content/product/highfrequency/siliconrf/module/ra08h1317m.pdf) powered by 14V DC.

**How do I choose an RF coupling capacitor?**

I have found [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/116497/81178), but it only applies to the frequency, not power. What power rating can I expect from an 0805 or 1206 MLCC?

Comment: um, what impedance does your system have / what's the peak voltage across that cap?

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't know the exact RF voltage. The PA is powered from 14V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At page 7, on the equivalent circuit of the RA08H1317M, the output is already AC coupled. Same thing on page 1 on the block diagram.

If you need to AC couple outside of the component anyway, then you have to find the power dispated by the capacitor due to ESR:

\$P_{cap}=R_{ESR} \cdot I^2=\frac{R_{ESR}}{R_{50Ω}} \cdot P_{RF}<\frac{0.1Ω}{50Ω} \cdot 10W=20mW\$

This is close to the typical power rating for size 0603. Size 0805 and 1206 should have no problem if you asume an ESR below 100mΩ. You should probably use a NPO dielectric.